# Email View Action MarkUp Not working

Tags: google-schemas

I added below code for perform ViewAction Markup for email, but it is not working. Help me resolving this issue.

Here inside `{1}` we are passing URL and its value is able set.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "potentialAction": {{
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "{1}",
    "name": "Book now"
    }},
    "description": "Book your bus seat now"
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "name": "Book now"
    },
    "description": "Book your bus seat now"
}
</script>
```

You should get the following button:

[image]

You can also check out the example on the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action

Comment: @meRa when comparing your markup to the View Action documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action) , it looks like you have incorrect syntax. I suggest following the example on the documentation. Also, if you haven't done so, you have to be whitelisted for Gmail actions, so I would register first. You can find more info at this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en.

Comment: As far as I can see: The examples at Google state to use 'target' (for the URL), but when running the [Email Markup Test from Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) it's missing an URL parameter. I have just added both, target and URL.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get this working using microdata and it seems like although the docs (still) have a `target` itemprop it should actually be `url`..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "name": "Book now"
    },
    "description": "Book your bus seat now"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to explain why and how your solution works? It will help understanding where the error was.